# Limit of an infinite summation

Tags: symbolic, summation, series-expansion

[image]

The above is from Maple 2019.1. Is there a way to achieve the same result from MMA12?

Tried

```
Limit[Sum[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {k, 1, n}], {n -> Infinity}]
```

which did not work. Best I can get is a numerical approximation.

```
With[{n = 10^200}, NSum[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {k, 1, n}]]
```

> > 0.166667

which is `informative`.

Comment: Can try this `With[{n = 10^200}, NSum[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {k, 1, n}]] // Rationalize`

Comment: @PlatoManiac Nice cheat :)

Comment: I totally agree ;)

Comment: `With[{n = 10^220}, NSum[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {k, 1, n}]]` yields `-0.333333` in *Mathematica* 12.0.

Comment: @mjw - For v12 use `With[{n = 10^220},
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 700},
   NSum[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {k, 1, n},
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]]] // Rationalize`

Comment: @Bob, nice!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some trickery: introduce a regulator to improve the convergence, which allows you to expand in $1/n$, and finally take the limit explicitly:

```
Series[(Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1) E^(-ϵ k), {n, ∞, 6}]
```

$$
\left(\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{n^3}+1}-1\right) e^{-\epsilon k}=e^{-\epsilon k}\left(\frac{k^2}{2 n^3}-\frac{k^4 }{8 n^6}+\mathcal O(n^{-7})\right)
$$

```
Sum[(E^(-k ϵ) k^2)/(2 n^3) - (E^(-k ϵ) k^4)/(8 n^6), {k, 1, n}]
Limit[%, ϵ -> 0]
```

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{n^3}+1}-1\right) e^{-\epsilon k}=\frac{40 n^5+54 n^4+5 n^3-10 n^2+1}{240 n^5}+\mathcal O(\epsilon)
$$

```
Limit[%, n -> ∞]
```

$$
\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame that [`AsymptoticSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSum) doesn't work out of the box for this problem. We can help it along by expanding the expression around $n=\infty$ and then using [`AsymptoticSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSum). Here is the expansion:

```
coeff = SeriesCoefficient[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {n, Infinity, m}];
coeff //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{m}{3}} k^{2 m/3} & (m \bmod 3)=0\land m>0 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

The only nonzero terms are when $m$ is a positive multiple of 3. Let's check by resumming the individual terms:

```
Sum[k^(2 m)/n^(3 m) Binomial[1/2, m], {m, Infinity}]
```

> -1 + Sqrt[(k^2 + n^3)/n^3]

Next, let's sum up the general coefficient using [`AsymptoticSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSum) to leading order:

```
terms[m_] = Assuming[
    m ∈ Integers && m > 0,
    Apart[
        FullSimplify @ AsymptoticSum[k^(2 m)/n^(3 m) Binomial[1/2, m], {k, 1, n}, {n, Infinity, 1}],
        n
    ]
];
terms[m] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m} n^{1-m}}{2 m+1}+\frac{1}{2} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{m} n^{-m}$

Clearly, the leading term is order $n^{1-m}$ and comes from the first coefficient:

```
terms[1]
```

> 1/6 + 1/(4 n)

The $1/n$ dependence is incomplete as we need to include the $m=2$ coefficient as well.

```
terms[2]
```

> -1/(16 n^2) - 1/(40 n)

To get the $n$ series to a particular order, we can series expand the expression, and then use [`AsymptoticSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSum) on the series expansion to the right order:

```
expansion[order_] := 
    AsymptoticSum[
        Normal @ Series[Sqrt[1 + k^2/n^3] - 1, {n, Infinity, order}],
        {k, 1, n},
        {n, Infinity, Max[Floor[order/3] - 1, 1]}
    ]
```

For example:

```
expansion[20] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{651}{66560 n^5}+\frac{5}{352 n^4}-\frac{17}{1152 n^3}+\frac{5}{168
>    n^2}+\frac{9}{40 n}+\frac{1}{6}$